# Eclipse shortcut to always run the same project

Tags: android, eclipse

My workspace is made up of one Android project and several other projects that my Android project depends upon. The Android project is the only project out of my workspace that I want to ***Run***.

How can I always ***Run*** the Android project without having to do

**Right click** -> **Run as..** but instead by pressing a shortcut no matter what file I'm currently editing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do following steps:

Go to Eclipse/Window > Preferences > Run/Debug > Launching

Select 'Always launch the previously launched application' in the 'Launch Operation' section.

Then just use your shortcut of choice. I think Ctrl + F11 is the default for this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should just select the project which you want to run and then press`Ctrl+F11`. It will run your currently selected project.

You may also get more shortcut of eclipse using `Ctrl+Sift+L`

Answer (score 1):

I read on here somewhere that you can select "Always launch the previously launched application" in the Launch Operation section, found in Window > Preferences > Run/Debug > Launching.

Then you use Ctrl F11 to launch.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But I marked Rizzz86 answer as correct, because it includes a picture and is a little more helpful to future visitors of the site..

Answer (score 0):

You could mark the other projects as libraries. But I think there is no possibility to run always a specified application.

Answer (score 0):

In the drop down of RUN, there is a option organize Favorite,
You can your project to favorite, and then press Ctrl + F11.
It will prioritize your favourite project first.

Then every time time of run the project, you just have to press Ctrl + F11